# What are the last three digits of the product of the odd numbers from 1 to 1000?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, decimal-expansion

> What are the last three digits of the product of the odd numbers from $1$ to $1000$?

Thank you in advance, any help is appreciated.

Comment: 1000 is not odd ....

Comment: @Andreas: and so? We are asked to compute $$999!!\pmod{1000}.$$

Comment: yeah, logically fine. Syntactically, I prefer questions which are not expressed indirectly. A question of taste, I guess.

Comment: If the question were the sum of all the perfect perfect numbers less than 1000 it'd be understood that 1000 may not be perfect but stating the question directly add all the perfect number less than or equal to whatever the last perfect square < 1000 is, is unnecessary.  I don't see that this is an more of a crime.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We have that $999!!$ is a multiple of $125$ since $125$ is one of its factors.
 On the other hand, $999\equiv 7\pmod{8}$, hence

$$ 999!!=\prod_{n=0}^{499}(2n+1)\equiv(1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7)^{125}\equiv 1\pmod{8} $$
By the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), it follows that 
$$ 999!!\equiv \color{red}{625}\pmod{1000}.$$

Comment: An upvote after $3$ seconds. Record!

Comment: I don't see how the modulo of 999 regarding 8 plays a role here ? (Second line)

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful: we have to find $N\pmod{1000}$, and we do that by computing $N\pmod{8}$ and $N\pmod{125}$. If we reduce $\pmod{8}$ every odd number in the range $[1,999]$, we get $$999!!\equiv 1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot 1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots\color{red}{7}\pmod{8}$$ from which $$999!!\equiv 1\pmod{8}$$ as explained above.

Comment: I understand that, but the second line stating that 999=7 mod 8 seems to be orthogonal to all that. Is that line in any way necessary ? For me it seems that from 1=1 mod 8 and the natural progression of 2n+1 through mod 8, everything is clear, without having to state 999=7 mod 8.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful: $999\equiv 7\pmod{8}$ is needed to prove that by writing $999!!\pmod{8}$ as $1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots$ we actually stop at a seven!

Comment: But that is clearly the same as saying that the terms of the product $$\prod_{n=0}^{499}(2n+1)$$ can be grouped four-by-four.